# Angular ui-grid filtering after data refresh

Tags: ui-grid

We are using Angular ui-grid in our project. We have a grid in our project, that uses filtering (both using drop-downs and free-form text). Once the grid is refreshed and new data is got, we could see that the filtering values are not touched. However, we want the new data to be filtered using the old filtering values. How to do it using ui-grid? Please let us know.

Thanks
Udaya

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions i can think of are:

1. Using Single Filter:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/321_singleFilter

2. Manually filter the data first then pass to grid.